# Polymer get return value from element and use instance methods

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I am new to Polymer and would like to get a return value from an element inside its parent element.

Basically, on a button click, I want to load a dialog with a radio select form that will return the value of the checked radio button when the confirm button is clicked on the dialog. But, every time the dialog is opened, I want to clear the radio buttons and use an ajax call to re-load the list.

My problem is 1, that I cannot seem to use any member functions inside a Polymer object. And second, I don't think I am getting the "return" value properly from the dialog element.

Here is my parent element:

```
<dom-module id="opr-remote">
    <template>
        <paper-button raised on-tap="onTap" id="play-file">Play file</paper-button>
        <opr-play-file-dialog id="playFileDialogElement"></opr-play-file-dialog>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'opr-remote',

            onTap: (e) => {
                const id = e.target.getAttribute('id');

                if ('play-file' === id) {
                    this.playFileDialogElement.open((playPosition) => {
                        console.log('play position: ' + playPosition);
                    });
                }
            },
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Which opens the dialog fine, but here is my dialog element:

```
<dom-module id="opr-play-file-dialog">
    <template>
        <iron-ajax
            id="currentPlaylistAjax"
            url="/current-playlist"
            handle-as="json"
            last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}"
            on-response="handleResponse">
        </iron-ajax>

        <paper-dialog
            entry-animation="scale-up-animation"
            exit-animation="fade-out-animation"
            id="playFileDialog">

            <h2>Play file</h2>

            <paper-spinner active id="playFileLoadingSpinner"></paper-spinner>

            <paper-radio-group on-change="positionOnChange" id="positionRadio" attr-for-selected="value">
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse.data]]">
                    <paper-radio-button value="[[item.position]]">[[item.fileName]]</paper-radio-button>
                    <br />
                </template>
            </paper-radio-group>

            <div class="buttons">
                <paper-button dialog-dismiss>Cancel</paper-button>
                <paper-button dialog-confirm autofocus disabled id="playButton" on-tap="playPressed">Play</paper-button>
            </div>
        </paper-dialog>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'opr-play-file-dialog',

            _selectedPosition: -1,
            _playPositionCallback: null,

            clearSelectedPosition: () => {
                this.positionRadio.select(-1);
                this._selectedPosition = -1;
                this.playButton.disabled = true;
            },

            open: (playPositionCallback) => {
                this._playPositionCallback = playPositionCallback;
                console.log(this._selectedPosition);// is undefined
                // if this is un-commented, throws an error as it not being a function
                //this.clearSelectedPosition();
                this.positionRadio.hidden = true;
                this.playFileLoadingSpinner.hidden = false;
                this.playFileDialog.open();
                this.currentPlaylistAjax.generateRequest();
            },

            handleResponse: () => {
                //this.clearSelectedPosition();
                this.positionRadio.hidden = false;
                this.playFileLoadingSpinner.hidden = true;
            },

            positionOnChange: (e) => {
                const target = e.target;

                this._selectedPosition = target.value;
                this.playButton.disabled = false;
            },

            playPressed: (e) => {
                if (this._selectedPosition < 1) {
                    return;
                }

                this._playPositionCallback(this._selectedPosition);
            },
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

As you can see, I cannot call `clearSelectedPosition`. Then, I am using a callback to get the position but I don't think this is the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple problems:

1. In your callbacks, you're referencing your elements by `this.ID`, but the correct syntax is to use `this.$.ID` (assuming those elements are not dynamically created) (see [Automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding). There are a few more instances of this problem in your code, and I've listed only one below.

   Change this:

   ```
   clearSelectedPosition() {
     this.positionRadio.select(-1);
     ...
   }
   ```

   To this:

   ```
   clearSelectedPosition() {
     this.$.positionRadio.select(-1);
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Your Polymer object's methods are defined with ES6 arrow functions, which are capturing the outer context (typically the `Window` object). You could confirm this by logging `this` inside your callbacks. You should use classic functions here instead to ensure that the Polymer object itself is used as the method context. You can still use arrow functions inside your methods.

   Change this:

   ```
   Polymer({
     is: 'opr-play-file-dialog',

     clearSelectedPosition: () => {},
     open: (playPositionCallback) => {},
     handleResponse: () => {},
     positionOnChange: (e) => {},
     playPressed: (e) => {},
   });
   ```

   To this:

   ```
   Polymer({
     is: 'opr-play-file-dialog',

     clearSelectedPosition: function() {},
     open: function(playPositionCallback) {},
     handleResponse: function() {},
     positionOnChange: function(e) {},
     playPressed: function(e) {},
   });
   ```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zoVqJo?editors=1011)

Alternatively, you could [define a Polymer 1 element with an ES6 class](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/es6):

```
class OprPlayFileDialog extends HTMLElement {
  beforeRegister() {
    this.is = 'opr-play-file-dialog';

    this.properties = {
      playlist: {
        type: Array,
        value: () => []
      }
    };
  }

  clearSelectedPosition() {}
  open(playPositionCallback) {}
  handleResponse() {}
  positionOnChange(e) {}
  playPressed(e) {}
}
Polymer(OprPlayFileDialog);
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/vyqGzj?editors=1011)